# csv implementation with cal-heatmap jquery

Tags: jquery, d3.js, heatmap

I have been attempting to use cal-heatmap with a csv to display data. However nothing seems to make it work. There are no errors in the console.

cal-heatmap: http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/
Does anyone have any clue on how to make it work with csv files? Or even have an example with a csv? Does anyone have any alternatives that are easily to implement with Google Analytics?

**THE CODE:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cal-heatmap.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cal-heatmap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="cal-heatmap"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cal = new CalHeatMap();
    cal.init({
    data: "test.csv",
    dataType: "csv",
    start: new Date(2013, 0),
    domain : "day",
    subDomain : "hour",
    itemName: ["visit", "visits"],
    range : 12,
    cellsize: 15,
    cellpadding: 3,
    cellradius: 5,
    domainGutter: 15,
    weekStartOnMonday: 0,
    scale: [40, 60, 80, 100]
    });
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**FORMAT OF CSV:**

```
Hour,Visits
000000,53
000001,40
000002,58
000003,45
000004,35
000005,37
000006,41
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Cal-heatmap does only understand data formatted like a JSON object.

**BUT**, you can set the `dataType` to `csv`, and use the csv parser, as in your example.
The reason it doesn't works out of the box is because after parsing, the resulting JSON object returned by `d3.csv()` do have keys, and looks like that :

```
[
    {
        "Hour": 000000,
        "Visits": 53
    },
    ...
]
```

You'll need to convert that back to something like that:

```
{
    "000000": 53,
    ...
}
```

Use the following function as your `afterLoad()` callback:

```
function(data) {
    "use strict";

    var d = {};
    var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    var i, total;
    for (i = 0, total = data.length; i < total; i++) {
        d[data[i][keys[0]]] = parseInt(data[i][keys[1]], 10);
    }
    return d;
}
```

That will take care of the conversion. This function will work only if the first column is the timestamp, and the second column, the value. Adjust `keys[n]` to your need if your CSV has a different structure.

AFAIK, Google Analytics does not use timestamp, so you have to incorporate the timestamp conversion in the function above.

Future version of Cal-Heatmap will do this conversion automatically.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Cal-HeatMap site](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/#data-format)

> Cal-Heatmap only understand data formatted in a JSON object like

However, you could use d3's [d3.csv](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) function to import your csv data into the format you need (although I haven't tested this).